# Center text between two pipe symbols

Tags: python-3.x, string-formatting

python question.

I want to print text between two pipe symbols, i want the text to be centered.

as:

```
|  Name  |  class  |  Number  |  Grade  |
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
name = 'John'
class_ = 'Class 1'
number = '2'
grade = 'Pass'

str = '| {} | {} | {} | {} |'.format(name, class_, number, grade)
str = str.center(80)

print(str)
```

To get the terminal size, here's a link:

[Get current terminal size on Linux, Mac, and Windows](https://gist.github.com/jtriley/1108174)

Edit 1:

To center individual fields:

```
name = 'John'
class_ = 'Class 1'
number = '2'
grade = 'Pass'

nameWidth = 10
classWidth = 10
numberWidth = 10
gradeWidth = 10

name = name.center(nameWidth)
class_ = class_.center(classWidth)
number = number.center(numberWidth)
grade = grade.center(gradeWidth)

str = '|{}|{}|{}|{}|'.format(name, class_, number, grade)

print(str)
```

Edit 2:

```
a = ['abcd','bc','cdef','d','e']
n = [1,2,3,4,5]
for i,e in zip(a,n):
    i = i.center(5)
    e = str(e).center(1)    # This line is not needed when width is 1
    s = '|{}|{}|'.format(i, e)
    print(s)
```

Comment: thank you, you answered mt question, but if you don't mind how can I implement this on a for loop for many 2 list.

Comment: code:a = ['abcd','bc','cdef','d','e']
n = [1,2,3,4,5]


for i,e in zip(a,n):
    mid  = ' '*(5-len(i))
    last = ' '*(1-len(str(e)))
    print('|',i,mid,'|',e,last,'|')